# WildcardPatternSuite finds no classes

Tags: java, junit, junit4, test-suite, filepattern

I'm trying to use the `WildcardPatternSuite` from [junit-toolbox](http://code.google.com/p/junit-toolbox/), but the testsuite fails with

```
java.lang.Exception: failed to scan C:\Users\ms\workspaces\comet4\PubServerTests\build\com\priint\pubserver\tests\testsuites using wildcard patterns [**/*Test.class] -- org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError
    at org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError.<init>(InitializationError.java:32)
    at com.googlecode.junittoolbox.WildcardPatternSuite.findSuiteClasses(WildcardPatternSuite.java:128)
    at com.googlecode.junittoolbox.WildcardPatternSuite.getSuiteClasses(WildcardPatternSuite.java:54)
    at com.googlecode.junittoolbox.WildcardPatternSuite.<init>(WildcardPatternSuite.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.<init>(JUnit4TestReference.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.<init>(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The code is

```
package com.priint.pubserver.tests.testsuites;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.googlecode.junittoolbox.SuiteClasses;
import com.googlecode.junittoolbox.WildcardPatternSuite;
@RunWith(WildcardPatternSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({"**/*Test.class"})
public class AllTests {}
```

The test classes are in packages below `com.priint.pubserver.` and are called `*Test`, i.e. `EntityTest`.

I'm using Eclipse 4.3 and starting the test suite with "Run As -> JUnit Test"

What's wrong here?

**Edit**: It seems the pattern `"**/*Test.class"` does start at the current package, i.e. it finds no classes in packages "above" the current package. Is there a pattern that traverses "up"?

Comment: According to the source code (version 1.8), there is no pattern to traverse up.

Comment: Now there is, check version 2.4 (2017) and https://github.com/MichaelTamm/junit-toolbox/issues/16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your class to a package that is a super package of all the classes that shall be run by the test suite.